# Using template images on LaunchScreen storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tintcolor, launch-screen

I've had good results using vector pdf files as template images for my iOS app. They make it easy to change colors and the graphics are always nice and sharp.

But now, as I'm finishing up my app and finalizing my launch screen, template rendering for image files used on the launch screen doesn't seem to work the same way. It looks like it might not be possible to get programmatic access to image tint color for images on the launch screen.

Am I stuck with hand-managing colors in this one section of the app, or is there a way to use the same technique on the launch screen?

Just to clarify, here's how I'm doing it in the main app:
1) I have a small collection of images in my assets folder. They're all vector .pdf files.
2) Each of this images has the "Scale Factors" attribute set to "Single Vector," and the "Render As" attribute set to "Template Image."
3) I set an app-wide default color in my app delegate using [this technique](https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial).
4) Each image then gets assigned a color programmatically in the view controller. Change it once, change it everywhere.

You can set the color for the launch screen template image by setting the global tint on the launch screen storyboard, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do this and leverage the color template framework I'm using in the rest of the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. please read this article before asking a question  to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask